# FileInputStream read file keep returning 0

Tags: java, android, inputstream, java-io

I am using FileInputStream to read a file on android phone. But when I used the FileInputStream.read to read data into array, the return value is always 0. I have checked that the path and file name is correct. Whats the possible reasons?

```
in = new FileInputStream(inFilename)
int readsize = 0;//Read size keep returning 0. 
do{
    readsize = in.read(data);
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Readsize:"+readsize);
    out.write(data);
} while(readsize > 0 );
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis data is an array. And I found the issue was caused by  initialized this array(data) with a 0 size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is only possible if you supplied a zero-length buffer, or a zero count in the case of the three-argument read.

NB The write line should be

```
out.write(data, 0, readsize);
```

and the loop should be written as

```
while ((readsize = in.read(data)) > 0)
{
    out.write(data, 0, readsize);
}
```

The way you have it, you're calling `write()` at end of stream, which isn't correct.

You don't need to initialize `readsize` either.

Comment: Couldn't it also happen if inFilename referred to an empty file?

Comment: @DavidConrad No, that would return -1.

Comment: @EJP Thanks a lot. I did not think about array I put in was 0 size. Your answer helped me solve this problem！